# openbox+fbpanel: highlight current window when using Alt + Tab

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, desktop, openbox, fbpanel

I am using `openbox` `3.6.1-8` on Debian 10. When I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through open windows, I see the preview of the applications as I am cycling through them in the middle of my screen:

[image]

unfortunately the icons in the taskbar do not change accordingly.
Is there a way to have the currently highlighted application also be highlighted in the taskbar, so that I can see in the taskbar which application is currently selected in the "cycle-selector", too?

The taskbar is actually provided by `fbpanel`, but I am not sure if `fbpanel` plays any role in this.

Comment: The taskbar `fbpanel` you are using does not support it.  I think I have managed in the past with `tint2` and executors, but I can't find it.  You could also try gnome-panel if it can be configured to do so.